# What is the idiomatic way to parse things in D?

Tags: d

Say I want to parse jquery selector syntax and turn things into tokens.

Should I parse things as an array of bytes? As a string with std.string? Char by char or maybe there's boyer-moore search somewhere in phobos? D has the fastest regex so maybe regex?

If someone could link to any good parsers written in D that would also be appreciated.

Comment: "One does not simply parse things in D..."

Comment: I would use Pegged - https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/Pegged/wiki

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pegged](https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/Pegged/wiki) is simple to use parser generator

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little CSS selector thing in my dom.d file:

https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff

Grab just the files dom.d and characterencodings.d if you want to play with it.

The way I did it is to use std.string. I wouldn't call this idiomatic or even good... but it was simple to write and got the job done for me. Selector strings are so short I don't think speed would matter much anyway.

For the html parser, I did that char by char. A more idiomatic way would probably be to be templated on an input range and return an output range. I did something more like this for a toy example a while ago:

http://arsdnet.net/dcode/lex.d

Again, I won't say this is the ideal D way... or even a good D way, but it is one possibility that can be made to work.